# How to print Powerquery code to Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I got about 90 Powerqueries in my Excel workbook, some of them with quite extensive code. In order to review the code and check the queries' logic, I want the code of all queries to be printed into a worksheet (rather then opening each query and the Advanced Editor and copying and pasting the code).
Couldn't find anything in the Internet. Also tried recording a macro but it doesn't record anything that's done in the Query Editor. Also saved the Excel file as .zip and searched for anything helpful in the xml-files - no success.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: [Look here](http://excelunplugged.com/2018/01/23/modifying-power-query-m-code-with-vba/). They get the query code by using `ThisWorkbook.Queries(<QUERYNAME>).Formula`

Comment: Thanks hsan! That works great for one query. But how to get the codes from all the queries? Replacing the query name with a variable and looping through all the names (`Dim qt As QueryTable`, `For Each qt In ws.QueryTables`, `ThisWorkbook.Queries(qt).Formula` and so forth yields nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all `collections` in VBA, you can access the elements by *name* or by *index*.
The following code adds a new sheet "Queries" at the end of a workbook and lists all queries.

```
Sub ListQueries(Optional wb As Workbook = Nothing)

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    wb.Sheets.Add after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        .Name = "queries"
        .Range("A1") = "Name"
        .Range("B1") = "Query"
        .Range("B:B").ColumnWidth = 150

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To wb.Queries.Count
            .Range("A" & i + 1) = wb.Queries(i).Name
            .Range("B" & i + 1) = wb.Queries(i).Formula
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```